# how to pass data to another screen using react native router flux?

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm trying to pass the data to another screen and I did this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state {
        qty: '',
    }
}
```

TextInput:

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Quantity"
    underlineColorAndroid={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({qty: text})}
    numberOfLines={4}
    style={styles.textstyleinputed1}
/>
```

Button:

```
<TouchableHighlight style = {styles.button} onPress={()=>Actions.gotoMap(this.state.qty)} underlayColor="transparent">
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>NEXT</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Here's how I call in the other screen

```
<Text>{this.props.qty}</Text>
```

and nothing's showed. I dont know what's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass data using action from router flux, you must define the name of the props that you want to pass to other component like this :

`Actions.gotoMap({ QTY : this.state.qty });`

And then you can get in gotoMap component like this :

`<Text>{this.props.QTY}</Text>`

I hope this answer can help you :)